# Download and save install files for Moonlight

Tags: firefox

Where can I just download a copy of Moonlight? The official page will only let me install it in Firefox and not download and save the install files.

Thanks in advance. Bob.

Comment: ?? Right click and save as the download link?

Answer (score 1):

Goto `http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx`

Select what version you want.

Right click the 'download the plugin' box and select "save as" in the context menu.